# Chef 12 CentOS 6.6 No candidate version available

Tags: centos, chef

I'me trying to install a custom package from a custom repo. The chef-client run is giving me this error:

```
No candidate version available for ruby-2.3.3
=============================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[ruby-2.3.3]'
```

But I can install it manually:

```
yum install ruby-2.3.3
.........
.........
===================================================================================================================
Installing:
 ruby                      x86_64                   2.3.3-1.el6                        vmc-misc                    16 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libyaml                   x86_64                   0.1.3-4.el6_6                      vmc-base                    52 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 16 M
Installed size: 46 M
```

**How can I get Chef to install this package?**

Answer (score 0):

You want to give just the name:

```
package 'ruby'
```

Or if you want to specify a single version:

```
package 'ruby' do
  version '2.3.3'
end
```